# Headset to HTC Desire?

Tags: htc-desire, headphones

I'm looking for a **wired** headset to my Desire (no pun intended ;)). My clients complain about sound quality when I use the one that comes with the phone.

All suggestions are welcome.

(I would have made this question a community wiki @ StackOverflow, please do so instead of closing it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used both quality Bluetooth and wired headsets adapters with my HTC Desire without anybody complaining about sound quality. In general I don't think you can go wrong with [Plantronics](http://www.plantronics.com) headsets, I've been using their landline ones for years.